# How can I type in the avogadro constant ("N" with subscript "A")?

Tags: macos, unicode

I can't find a way to type in a subscript "A" into the keyboard. Could not find any unicode character for it and could not find a unicode character for "N" with an "A" as a subscript.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You don't mention a specific environment, should we assume macOS (and if yes, which version)? Which application are you using, can't you just format the A as a subscript?

Comment: latest version of macos. Using an IDE called "Comma". I need a unicode character. Doesn't looks like this can be done. Best thing I found was a small capital "A": Nᴀ

Comment: Perhaps you can elaboarate slightly on what your goal is? Are you writing plaintext documents? Is it for another goal? Anyway, I'm sure you're aware, but if you're doing any technical writing LaTeX is a more suiting solution than plaintext. Is there any reason you can't use TeX?

Comment: This is an IDE, I need unicode characters.

Comment: I see, but what are you typing in the IDE? Is it code? Is it documentation? ASCII art?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Unicode character for subscript A to form N<sub>A</sub> without any markup. This can be found on the [wiki on Unicode sub- and superscripts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts) .